# Is there a solution for $e^{-x} = \ln(x)?$

Tags: calculus

Is there a solution for $e^{-x} = \ln(x)?$

Should I use the I.V.T theorem as an approach to this problem?

Comment: IVT is the way to go, yes. Think about the function $f(x) = e^{-x} - \log(x)$. Can you prove that $f$ has to be zero somewhere?

Comment: Yes, there is a solution!  If you plot $y_1 = e^{-x}$ and $y_2=\ln x$, you will see that they intersect.  To find a solution in closed form, other than by some numerical method, such as iteration, I don't think so ...

Comment: What is the IVT theorem?

Comment: @mjw Intermediate Value Theorem

Comment: @mjw It states that if a continuous function goes from $y=a$ to $y=b$ from $x_1$ to $x_2$, there will be a value $x$ such that $f(x) = c$ for $c \in (a, b)$.

Comment: Okay, thanks! ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$ Or I should write:  TYVM!

Comment: By the way, the IVT theorem is the "intermediate value theorem theorem."

Comment: See [A201942](http://oeis.org/A201942).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can be transformed into an equivalent one, by taking exponentials, i.e., finding the solution of equation:

$$\underbrace{x}_{g(x)=Id(x)}=\underbrace{\exp(\exp(-x))}_{f(x)}\tag{1}$$

The same arguments used by my fellow colleagues in their different answers are valid for continuous functions $f$ and $g=id$ ($f$ decreasing, $g$ increasing, with $f(0)>g(0)$ and $f(3)<g(3)$, yielding a unique solution $x=x_0$ to equation (1).

**But there is more to say** about form (1): it is the so-called [fixed-point solution](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/metric/metric_public/numerical_methods/iteration/fixed_point_iteration.html) to the iteration:

$$u_{n+1}=f(u_n), \ \ u_0=2.5 \ (arbitrary)$$

[image]

*Fig. 1: The curve of $f$, the straight line representing $id$, both defined in (1), and a form of spiral materializing the convergence of iterative sequence $u_{n+1}=f(u_n)$.*

which is convergent with a rather good behavior because around the root $x_0$, the "shrinking factor" $s=f'(x_0) \approx -0.3535$ (minus sign being a testimony of alternate convergence), visualized on the graphics above), giving, in less than 40 iterations steps, a $\approx 10^{-15}$ precision (see remark below):

$$x_0=1.309799585804151$$

**Remark:** Very precisely, only $n=36$ steps are needed because $36=\lceil -15/\log_{10}(0.3535)\rceil$.

Explanation: the errors defined by $e_n:=u_n-x_0$ are decreasing at each step in absolute value with a "shrinking rate" governed by |s| in the following manner

$$|e_{n}|\approx |s||e_{n-1}|$$

we have $|e_n|=|s|^n|e_0|$ which we want to be $<10^{-15}$; taking $log_{10}$) one gets the constraint $n \log_{10}(|s|)+\log_{10}e_0<-15$, from which one can deduce the value of $n$.

Comment: No comment about this solution ? Don't forget that dialog has a large place on this site;

Answer (score 1):

The function $e^{-x}$ is decreasing and continuous for $x\ge 1$. The function $\log x$ is increasing and continuous for $x\ge 1$. The values of these functions at $1$  are $1/e$ and $0$. The values of these functions at $e$ are $e^{-e}<\log e=1$.  So yes, the equation has unique solution $x>1$.

Comment: You can even say $1<x<e$...

Comment: I could ${}{}{}$.

Comment: The solution of @user is incorrect: continuity of the functions are important for the conclusion. And logarithm can be taken only of positive numbers.

Comment: You are perfectly right. You should say him/her.

Answer (score 1):

Taking $\log$ both side we obtain

$$\log(e^{-x})=\log(\log x) \iff -x=\log(\log x)$$

and since both funtions are monotonic with

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \log(\log x)=\infty\quad \lim_{x\to 1^+} \log(\log x)=-\infty$$

one solution exists on the interval $(1,e)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=e^{-x}-\log(x)$$ its derivative $f'(x)=-e^{-x}-\frac{1}{x}$ is always negative so the solution is unique. For solving it, as said in comments and answers, a numerical method is required.

If you want an *approximation*, expand $f(x)$ as a series around $x=\frac e 2$ to get
$$f(x)=\left(e^{-e/2}-\log
   \left(\frac{e}{2}\right)\right)+\left(-\frac{2}{e}-e^{-e/2}\right)
   \left(x-\frac{e}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{2}{e^2}+\frac{e^{-e/2}}{2}\right)
   \left(x-\frac{e}{2}\right)^2+\left(-\frac{8}{3 e^3}-\frac{e^{-e/2}}{6}\right)
   \left(x-\frac{e}{2}\right)^3+O\left(\left(x-\frac{e}{2}\right)^4\right)$$ and use series reversion to get
$$x=\frac{e}{2}+t+\left(\frac{1}{e}+\frac{e-2}{2 \left(e+2 e^{e/2}\right)}\right)
   t^2+\frac{\left(e^4+8 e^e-e^{1+\frac{e}{2}} (8+(e-12) e)\right) t^3}{3 e^2
   \left(e+2 e^{e/2}\right)^2}+O\left(t^4\right)$$ where $t=\frac{f(x)-e^{-e/2}+\log \left(\frac{e}{2}\right)}{-\frac{2}{e}-e^{-e/2}}$.

Making $f(x)=0$ as desired, this gives as *estimate* $x=1.309799245$ which is not bad.

Answer (score 0):

Note that a solution is where the function graphs "cross" or intersect. If they intersect, it is at a particular value where $x$ $>$ $0$, since real values of $\ln(x)$ are not defined at negative values of $x$. Such intersection must also take place at a value of $y$ $>$ $0$ since $e^{-x}$ $>$ $0$. Since $e^{-x}$ is decreasing over $x>0$ and $\ln(x)$ is increasing over $x>0$, first verify that that $e^{-x}$ is greater than $\ln(x)$ anywhere that $x$ $>$ $0$: To do so, note that $\ln(1)$ $=$ $0$, and $e^{-1}$ $=$ $1/e$ is positive and therefore greater than $0$. Also note: $\ln(x)$ $\rightarrow$ $\infty$ as $x$ $\rightarrow$ $\infty$, but $e^{-x}$ $\rightarrow$ $0$ as $x$ $\rightarrow$ $\infty$.

By continuity, the graph of these functions must cross at some bounded location greater than $x=1$. Hence there is a solution to $\ln(x)$ $=$ $e^{-x}$.

Comment: No, functions $\phi(x)=exp(-x)$ and $\psi(x)=ln(x)$ are not reciprocal one of the other. This is true for $\phi(x)=exp(x)$ and $\psi(x)=ln(x)$

Comment: By inverse, I do not mean reciprocals--but you are correct, the -1 makes my statement incorrect. Thank you for correcting me.